# Using if statements when declaring values of an array

Tags: c#, if-statement

I've created some code as seen below for declaring the values of an array. However, I know there is another way to do this using if statements, would you be able to show me that way too? N,Q,L,R and K are the valid codes and the "default" one is when an invalid code (any letter except for the listed ones) is given.

Have put code below - also let me know if more info is needed:

```
public void setInfo(string c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case "K":
            event_code = event_codes[0];
            break;
        case "L":
            event_code = event_codes[1];
            break;
        case "R":
            event_code = event_codes[2];
            break;
        case "Q":
            event_code = event_codes[3];
            break;
        case "N":
            event_code = event_codes[4];
            break;
        default:
            event_code = "I";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use an if statement? Switch does nicely.

Comment: What is `event_codes`?

Comment: It would be cleaner as a switch *expression*, admittedly.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/1ca3abb70639411d6b8bceeea86d3882 for example - with some more conventional names.

Comment: I wouldn't change that to an if-clause. In your case it would make more sense to use a `Dictionary<char, string>` though. You can add the characters as keys and the codes as values. Afterwards you can just say `dict[c]` to get the value required. Keep in mind to check if the key exists like this: `if (dict.ContainsKey(c))`

Comment: okay cool - thanks guys! might leave it in then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the code as it is better to understand the process of using `switch` or `if` statements.

A `switch` statement just tells the compiler to compare the value of the parameter provided against each of the `case` statement values and if true to run the code between that and the next `break` keyword. At the `break` further processing of the `switch` stops.

Thus the `switch` can be thought of as:

`switch(s)` ---> is parameter `s`

`case "R":` ---> equal to "R"

if it is then run

`event_code = event_codes[2];`

`default` ---> `s` is not equal to any `case` condition so run

`event_code = "I";`

An `if` clause must return a logical result i.e., the statement must be true or false.

An `if` structure would be:

```
if (<some logical test>)
{ // test is true
    <run this code>
}
else
{ //test is false
    <run this code>
}
```

The `switch` can be replaced by a number of `if`s, but as you can see you will need one `if` for each `case`.

Don't forget the `default` clause - this is code that is run when all of the test conditions have failed and that you will need to duplicate the behaviour of the switch by not processing more `if` clauses after one has passed its logical test and run the code in the `test is true` section.

Comment: coool - thanks for the info, the comaprison was great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I like to use a hashmap, this makes it easier to update your list of values instead of adding more if statements every time you have a new code.
Here's a quick example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // use the set_event_code function to set the event code
    String event_code = "A";
    event_code = set_event_code(event_code);
    // output the event code
    Console.WriteLine("Event Code: " + event_code);
}
// create a function that sets the value of "event_code"
public static string set_event_code(String event_code)
{
    // create a hashmap of event_codes and the event_code passed will be the key to the value being set
    Dictionary<string, string> event_codes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    event_codes.Add("A", "event_code_1");
    event_codes.Add("B", "event_code_2");
    event_codes.Add("C", "event_code_3");
    event_codes.Add("D", "event_code_4");
    event_codes.Add("E", "event_code_5");
    // set the value of "event_code" to the value of the key passed, if the key does not exist, set the value to "event_code_0"
    if (event_codes.ContainsKey(event_code))
    {
        event_code = event_codes[event_code];
    }
    else
    {
        event_code = "event_code_0";
    }
    return event_code;
}
```

Comment: `return event_codes.TryGetValue(event_code, out var mapped_code) ? mapped_code : "event_code_0";`